# Best practice for refactoring database in Rails?

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with ruby on rails and I need to split a database named: Users, it is using devise for authentications, I have two types of users: investors and borrowers, and I want to split them in 2 tables.

The users's table has other relations: has_many and has_one.

thanks

Comment: Are they really completely different things or are they just users that have investor and/or borrower roles and permissions?

Comment: they are different things, each one has to have a control panel, different functionality